# Losing resolution using gdalwarp to change projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdalwarp, resolution, mars

I’m trying to project an image from Mars using `gdalwarp`, from eqc to polar stereo projection:

```py
gdalwarp -overwrite 
-s_srs "+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=3396190 +b=3376200 +units=m +no_defs" 
-t_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-90 +lon_0=0 +k=0.1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=3396190 +b=3376200 +units=m +no_defs" 
-of GTiff MarsEqc.TIF MarsStere.TIF
```

However, in the result I lost spatial resolution, as you can see in the image. As the original resolution is 1km/px I tried to change -tr and -ts options but with no good results.

[image: MarsStere.tif]

If I change the projection directly in QGIS the result is pretty good, without losing resolution. Of course to use QGIS would be a solution, but I have to process a lot of images.

[image: Image projected with QGIS]

What parameters do I have to add to maintain the original resolution?

Comment: Any hint [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73042/how-to-set-output-resolution-for-gdalwarp-to-that-of-source-file)?