# Why does this HDF4 file converted to .tif with gdal come out at a coarser resolution?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, modis, gdal-translate, gdalbuildvrt

I'm currently working with large-domain MODIS data. These come in multiple separate HDF4 files which I stitch together into a virtual data set (VRT), reproject into EPSG:4326, sub-set to the domain of interest and convert to .tif. This seems to work as expected.

When I repeat this procedure with a VRT that consists of only a single MODIS tile, the resulting .tif file for some reason comes out at about half the original resolution. Specifying a resolution for the VRT with e.g. `-resolution highest` does not change this. What am I missing here?

#### MWE

GDAL 3.0.4 with HDF4 support

Input file (11 MB): https://github.com/wknoben/gis_se/blob/main/MCD12Q1.A2015001.h10v03.006.2018146022714.hdf

```
gdalbuildvrt modis.vrt MCD12Q1.A2015001.h10v03.006.2018146022714.hdf -sd 1 -resolution highest
gdalwarp -of VRT -t_srs "EPSG:4326" modis.vrt modis_4326.vrt
gdal_translate -projwin -116.55 51.74 -115.52 50.95 modis_4326.vrt modis_4326_cut.vrt
gdal_translate -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" modis_4326_cut.vrt modis_4326_cut.tif
```

#### Source HDF and resulting tif

[image: Source HDF4 file in QGIS]

[image: Resulting .tif file in QGIS]

Comment: -tr option? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73042/how-to-set-output-resolution-for-gdalwarp-to-that-of-source-file

Comment: I tried that with `-resolution user -tr x y` (x and y found by looking at pixel size in the source hdf) but the result was the same.